# Turning off Permissions for Other Apps with Accessibility Services

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, accessibility

I previously saw an application called "Permission Manager" on the PlayStore that uses Accessibility Services in order to turn off Permissions for other applications.

I am aware of opening an application's permission settings programmatically through intents. However, once I do, how can I get the accessibility service to simulate touches on the screen to turn off the permissions for other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, launch the intent to modify apps' permissions. Then, you can use [getRootInActiveWindow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#getRootInActiveWindow()) to get the current window (which is now the settings window). Make sure that [getPackageName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#getPackageName()) is correct. Use [getViewIdResourceName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#getViewIdResourceName()) and [getChild(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#getChild(int)) to traverse the view hierarchy. When you found the view, [perform](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#performAction(int)) a [click](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#ACTION_CLICK) and return to your app.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I upvoted you but it doesn't count sadly. Thanks a lot again :)